# Using maven to create a standalone jar file that executes in any OS

Tags: testng, maven, pom

I am trying to create a standalone selenium-TestNG tests Jar file that can be executed in any OS as part of CI/CD.

My POM.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumTutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SeleniumJar</name>
  <description>SeleniumJar</description>
  
  <repositories> 
  <repository> 
    <id>jcenter</id> 
    <name>bintray</name> 
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url> 
  </repository> 
</repositories> 
  
  <dependencies>  


<!-- https://testng.org/doc/download.html -->
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId> 
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
  <version>6.10</version>  
</dependency> 


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.9</source>
          <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.testng.TestNG</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
   <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
    </plugin>
    

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>org.testng.TestNG</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


             
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am using eclipse and built this project using goal "clean install". On build completion 3 Jar files got created:

> original-SeleniumTutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> SeleniumTutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> SeleniumTutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies

On executing these jar files using the command "java -jar ", I get the below error:

[image: On running jar files I get this message]

How to proceed from here, how to create a standalone Jar file that on running the command runs the TestNG tests

**Note:** https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/39529/40022 suggest some implementation but I am not sure how to create the package in maven, and I cannot comment in that post as I dont have enough reputation

Comment: Does it need to be an executable jar?  We use maven in Bamboo here, and we just use maven lifecycle commands, e.g. "mvn test" to run the tests as part of a build.

Comment: and you will be using just the pom.xml ?

Comment: yeah the POM and an entry to point it to the xml file, as described here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: When I try that it says textng.xml not found , I have to manually place the file in that location. What to do to make sure the text.xml is available  without having to provide it separately